# Android Customtitlebar issue?

Tags: android, custom-titlebar

```
      I am Developing an application which consists of custom-title-bar.
```

1.I have implemented custom title bar in my application,until here every thing is working fine for me.

2.I have removed the custom title bar in splash screen,when i am loading the application in emulator, Before the splash screen,custom-title-bar is loading and then splash screen is displayed.

3.my requirement is i need to display the custom-title-bar before the splash-screen.

Comment: is your custom title bar an activity?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your problem is, your main(launcher) activity contains custom title bar, it launches splash screen which is not containing title bar. So it is obvious that title bar is gonna hide behind splash screen.
 If you dont wanna implement custom title bar in splash screen then it is advisable that you make your splash screen background's(image's) top "white and transparent"(with the help of photoshop) so that title bar of main activity is visible behind the splash screen.